# How to setup sub-domain with nginx based on Angular app uri

Tags: angularjs, nginx

This is my url: 
https://front.example.net/#/dashboard/partners/partner/**{partner_name}**/orders/list

I would like to setup subdomain for every {partner_name} via nginx.

For example, instead of: https://front.example.net/#/dashboard/partners/partner/**google**/orders/list
I want something like this: 
https://**google**.example.net/orders/list

Thnak you!

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'll first need to ensure that the subdomains resolve correctly so that the requests reach your webserver. 
You could do so with a wildcard `CNAME` entry.

You could then define a server block for each partner or use a wildcard like so

```
server {
  server_name ~^(.*)\.example\.net ;
  root /$1/;
}
```

where $1 now stores the name of your partner

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I don't want to redirect based on the directory name.
I want to use angular path instead